# Is there any way to save an ALAsset in a way that would work despite any changes to ALAssetLibrary?

Tags: iphone, alassetslibrary

I asked an earlier question similar to this (with no responses), but I know more about the problem, so I decided to rephrase it in a new one.  I hope this is ok.

Essentially, I need to store some ALAssets in my app, specifically photos from the Camera Roll/Photo Library.

If the user switches out of the app, then takes some pictures or deletes some pictures, then the ALAssets that I have stored become invalid.

Is there any way around this?  Is there any data from the ALAssets that I can store, such as a photo ID, a path, or anything, which will "survive" the ALAssetLibrary re-indexing itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when the PhotoLibrary changes, all AssetLibrary objects become invalid.
What you need to do:

1) Before the user switches out of the app, register an observer for ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification. Please note, that there is an iOS Bug that you need to work around: http://www.openradar.me/10484334

2) Before the user switches out of the app save the URLs of the ALAssets that you want to retrieve later using the method:

```
[assetObject valueForPropery: ALAssetPropertyURLs];
```

3) When the user switches back to your app (and changes were done), you observer should be called. If your UI displays any ALAsset Objects, you should trigger an reenumeration of the AssetsLibrary and update your GUI (otherwise your GUI reflects to invalid ALAssetsObjects).

4) To retrieve any of your the ALAsset-Objects, that you saved the URLs for before, use the method:

```
[assetsLibraryInstance assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock]
```

For assetURL pass the values you saved earlier.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: Thank you!  This did indeed work.  However, a clarification: would the app still receive the ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification if the app is in the background?

Comment: The app does not receive the notification, when it's in the background. But if any changes to the Photo Library occur, while the app is in the background, you receive the notification (one or multiple times) as soon as the app is in the foreground again.